# Subquery mysql with where clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

> Hello, Im stuck with mysql subquery, this is the table I have

```
table detail_order
==============================
id_detail | id_order | id_toko
1         | 1        | 1
2         | 1        | 2
3         | 1        | 3
4         | 1        | 4

table ket_detail
==================================
id_ket | id_detail | id_size | qty
1      | 1         | 7       | 3
2      | 1         | 9       | 1
3      | 1         | 5       | 2
4      | 2         | 7       | 8

table size
=================================
id_size | size | id_color | stock
7       | 40   | 6        | 30
9       | 42   | 6        | 20
5       | 39   | 5        | 30

table color
==========================
id_color | color
6        | green
5        | red
```

Im trying in subquery to show qty on table ket_detail with where clause, but when Im try it subquery return more than one row.
this is my query

```
SELECT dt.id_detail, 
       SUM(tk.qty) AS tot_order, 
       COUNT(dm.color) AS tot_color,
      (SELECT ket.qty FROM ket_detail AS ket, t_size AS u 
       WHERE u.id_size=ket.id_size AND u.size = 40) AS size_40
FROM detail_order AS dt 
LEFT JOIN ket_detail AS tk ON tk.id_detail=dt.id_detail
LEFT JOIN t_size AS u ON u.id_size = tk.id_size
LEFT JOIN t_color AS dm ON dm.id_color=u.id_color
WHERE dt.id_order = 1
GROUP BY dt.id_detail
```

but when I change size to 39 the data like this

```
id_detail | tot_order | tot_color | size_40
============================================
1         | 6         | 2         | 2
2         | 8         | 1         | 2
3         | NULL      | 0         | 2
4         | NULL      | 0         | 2
```

what do I want is the data like this

```
id_detail | tot_order | tot_color | size_40
============================================
1         | 6         | 2         | 3
2         | 8         | 1         | 8
3         | NULL      | 0         | NULL
4         | NULL      | 0         | NULL
```

Comment: You need to use a `JOIN` in your subquery to produce `id_size`-matching results, from a cursory look at your question.

Comment: Do sizes need ids? Why?

Comment: There is no `jumlah_order` field in table `ket_detail` in the sample data provided. The query makes use of this field though.

Comment: The results shown are 'correct' based on your data, as `size = 39` from `size` has a `qty` of '2'.   I think you need to explain a bit clearer as to what you're trying to do, as it's a bit muddled up.  Also, `jumlah_order` isn't in the table data you supplied.

Comment: You still don't need the surrogate keys. Your primary keys can be (id_detail), (id_detail,id_size), (size,id_color), and (id_color), respectively - although I'd also question the need for a color_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery to get the `size = 39` or `size = 40` data. You can use *conditional aggregation* instead:

```
SELECT dt.id_detail, 
       SUM(tk.qty) AS tot_order, 
       COUNT(dm.color) AS tot_color,
       SUM(CASE 
              WHEN u.size = 39 THEN tk.qty
              ELSE 0
           END)  AS size_39,       
       SUM(CASE 
              WHEN u.size = 40 THEN tk.qty
              ELSE 0
           END)  AS size_40        
FROM detail_order AS dt 
LEFT JOIN ket_detail AS tk ON tk.id_detail=dt.id_detail
LEFT JOIN t_size AS u ON u.id_size = tk.id_size
LEFT JOIN t_color AS dm ON dm.id_color=u.id_color
WHERE dt.id_order = 1
GROUP BY dt.id_detail;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/XKYR30434)

The proper way to do it with a subquery is:

```
SELECT dt.id_detail, 
       SUM(tk.qty) AS tot_order, 
       COUNT(dm.color) AS tot_color,
      (SELECT SUM(ket.qty) 
       FROM ket_detail AS ket
       JOIN t_size AS u ON u.id_size=ket.id_size
       WHERE ket.id_detail = dt.id_detail AND u.size = 40) AS size_40
FROM detail_order AS dt 
LEFT JOIN ket_detail AS tk ON tk.id_detail=dt.id_detail
LEFT JOIN t_size AS u ON u.id_size = tk.id_size
LEFT JOIN t_color AS dm ON dm.id_color=u.id_color
WHERE dt.id_order = 1
GROUP BY dt.id_detail;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TCTXU32773)

If you need to select the total quantity for more than one sizes, then you have to repeat the subquery for each required size. Hence, I think, the first query provides a solution that is cleaner, easier to extend and more efficient.